# php - adding messages and setting date

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I don't know php at all and try to rewrite an example [of using php with android](http://androidexample.com/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123%5D)

I want my android app to send some data - name and message and receive list of this data as JSON

now - what I have from my example :

```
<?php

    // Get Post Data
    $data = urldecode($_POST['data']);
    $name = urldecode($_POST['name']);

    $jsonData      = array();
    $jsonTempData  = array();


          $jsonTempData = array();
          $jsonTempData['name']         = $name;
          $jsonTempData['number']       = $data;
          $jsonTempData['date_added']   = // I don't know how to set date

          $jsonData[] = $jsonTempData;


     $outputArr = array();
     $outputArr['Android'] = $jsonData;

     // Encode Array To JSON Data
     print_r( json_encode($outputArr));


 ?>
```

which means I send some data and get it back in one method which is , I assume, wrong.
how can I separate them - sending data to php and receiving json.i have to repeat, I got zero knowledge in php.

Plus it's only one name-message pair wrapped into array and what I need is to make array of this messages and return them in JSON.Oh, and I need to write time of message into array

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jsonTempData['date_added']   = date('Y-m-d');//To set date
```

If you want various date formats check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

If you want to return the json data just do this (You can only return a value if you are using a function.)

```
return json_encode($outputArr);
```

if you want to dsplay it

```
echo json_encode($outputArr);
```

Comment: except this 2 modification...rest of code is fine..!!now your php code should work..!!

Comment: so... when I just ask my app to get JSON object from http://www.myurl.com/myphp.php - I get this - return json_encode($outputArr);  and if I need to store name and message into database - I use same http://www.myurl.com/myphp.php to send data to it? I just don't really understand mechanism - it works for receive and send in one code? so if I don't send nothing - it just gives me json encoded outputArr and if i send data - it don't return me JSON array?

Comment: if you need to store name and message into database than you should write the code on myphp.php for insert that values and you should get the json array by using the index ANDROID.

Comment: well .. as far as I understand,  $data = urldecode($_POST['data']);
 $name = urldecode($_POST['name']); are message(data) and name (name) already. So , what I need to know - is this particular code stores only one set of name/data/time ? and if it so - how can I just add a new message/name/time to my database?

Comment: No you are wrong ,it store each time the new entry of name/data/time whenever you call the  myurl.com/myphp.php...it all depend on you what data you are sending from app.

Comment: oh, thanx. then. how can I work with them? As I understand it - it is an array somewhere on server. For example, I want to add some more data to my array - it will be name/data/time/number_of_likes . Or anything else. And later I would want to change number_of_likes for 3rd entry, for example. How do I work not only by adding new entries but also find and work with older ones by it's index